# Derivative of a vector times constant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(\mathbf{x}) = \alpha \mathbf{x}$. Is the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \alpha \mathbf{J}$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \alpha \mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{J}$ is a matrix with all 1s and $\mathbf{I}$ is a standard $n \times n$ identity matrix? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe review the definition of derivative (how are the entries of the matrix defined?) and think about what each entry should be.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for the comment! Do you have a good reference for this?

Comment: It's $I$. For example, the first component of the result does not depend on the second component of $x$.

Comment: @Leo Thank you!

Comment: For this function it's easy to directly calculate $f(x+h)$ and compare it to the Taylor series.
$$\eqalign{
f(x+h) &= f(x) + \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg) h \\
\alpha x+\alpha h &= \alpha x + \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg) h \\
}$$
Which one of your proposed derivatives satisfies the series expansion?

Comment: I believe the answer should be a column vector of the dimension $n$ with $a$ as its elements.